# When did women start sailing (as passengers) on ocean-going ships in large numbers?

Tags: naval, women, navigation

My understanding is that women sailed on sail powered ships [(caravels)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caravel) such as the Mayflower. On the other hand, I have read few accounts of women sailing on earlier, oar-driven ships such as triremes or galleys. (OK, Cleopatra did at the [Battle of Actium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Actium), but she was Cleopatra.)

When did women start sailing as passengers on ships in meaningful numbers? Was it when wind-driven ships meant that it was no longer necessary for everyone to row their own weight, or was there an earlier dividing line?

This question relates to ocean-going vessels, and not ships on rivers or near the shore. (In the game,  "Civilization," a trireme (rowed boat) has a 50-50 chance of sinking if not adjacent to the shore. Admittedly, this is a game, but it illustrates a point that rowed vessels might not be considered safe enough for women on oceans.)

**Edit:**

When I refer to "women" on ocean-going ships, I do not include female slaves (who had no choice in the matter). And women who were the "wives of governors" would be included under the heading of "Cleopatra." So "women" in this context would refer to "middle class" women (neither rulers nor slaves) travelling on their own account.

Comment: When you talk about "sailling on" presumably you're talking about being part of the active crew and not just as passengers?

Comment: @SteveBird: I meant as passengers. My theory is that on rowing ships, just about every passenger aboard was needed to row, or otherwise double as "crew.". Or perhaps rowed ships were not safe enough for women (other than e.g. slaves) on long journeys

Comment: Maybe it is more about the difference between ships for settlers/passengers and ships for war or trade. Tourism or large move of settlers were maybe not common in ancient times.

Comment: I had always imagined that when the Greeks were colonizing the Mediterranean that they were bringing entire households along (wives, children and servants), I don't have evidence of that tho.

Comment: I assume you want a little more than the trivial answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynesia#History

Comment: I am fairly certain there are known cases of Romans bringing spouses when they went off to govern a province.  I am near certain Roman sailing vessels could carry significant non-crew personnel.  Navel combat of that era was all about ramming and boarding enemy ships.  If you are boarding other ships, you presumably have to plan on not all your marines returning, which implies that the crew needed to move the boat is significantly lower than the number of people it could carry.

Comment: Also, Greek Triremes were used to [transport horses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trireme).  If you can transport significant number of horses, you can transport significant numbers of non-crew.

Comment: Many European settlers in the New World, for example, married native omen for lack of European women.  But the European colonists were not all men, there were a number of women in the colonies.  For example the English colonists left on Roanoke Island in 1587 included 90 men, 17 women, and 11 children, some female. So women began making long sea voyages at least as early as 1587 and groups of adult colonists may have usually included about 10 to 20 percent women since about 1587 or earlier.

Comment: @StevenBurnap: I would include the "spouses" of governors under the heading of "Cleopatra." And, of course, female slaves would be transported. So my real question related to "middle class" women travelling on their own account.

Comment: In A.D. 300s, a wealthy Roman woman named Melania took "various high-born women and children" on a ship with herself to Alexandria. [Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=HF0m3spOebcC&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=%22ancient+rome%22+women+ship&source=bl&ots=q1PtrsE5lE&sig=sK-sPifRuTp2fOmCeklDM59AQzA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnyZaNptnSAhVEVWMKHc1FDpAQ6AEIVjAO#v=onepage&q=ship&f=false)

Comment: @MAGolding: Your comment is the closest thing around to a good answer. Would you help me reopen the question so that you can answer it?

Comment: Given that "middle class" is a Victorian invention, I think the question answers itself. I'm not sure that colony ships like the Mayflower count as middle class passengers. (I might be distracted by the term "middle class"

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: This is still a "work in progress" so I will finish making the changes that I've started before trying to reopen the question. But I have finished making improvements  on this question: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/61707/were-the-japanese-kongo-class-battlewagons-advanced-for-their-time?noredirect=1#comment191809_61707. Will you be the "fifth" (not "moderator") vote to reopen it or at least tell me why it should remain closed? Some, (but not all) VTC people have voted to reopen.